# Error al ejecutar nodemon en Node.js: [nodemon] Internal watch failed: Circular symlink detected:

Tags: nodejs

Estoy aprendiendo a hacer *API* creando un backend con *NodeJS*. Cuando intento ejecutar *nodemon* me salta este error:

> [nodemon] Internal watch failed: Circular symlink detected:"C:\Users\davidjose\AppData\Local\Datos de programa" points to "C:\Users\davidjose\AppData\Local"

Answer (score 1):

Has probado haciendo la instalación global de nodemon? `npm nodemon -g`.
También puedes probar con `npx nodemon`. Este segundo comando lo que hace es buscar nodemon, y si no lo encuentra lo instala.